# Vertical d3.svg.area?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, charts, area

I'm trying to make a vertical area chart, with a line in it's right borders. Line is being drawn perfectly ( top to bottom ), but the area is being drawn on right side of the path, it should be on the left.

I started with a horizontal chart, it worked then. See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ecq3j2qx/12/). I've also tried rotating the path but cannot get desired result.

```
var xScale = d3.scale.linear().range([0, sm_width]),
    yScale = d3.time.scale().range([0, sm_height]);

var area = d3.svg.area().x(function(d) {
    return xScale(xValue(d));
})
.y0(sm_height).y1(function(d) {
    return yScale(yValue(d));
});

var line = d3.svg.line().x(function(d) {
    return xScale(xValue(d));
})
.y(function(d) {
    return yScale(yValue(d));
});
```

Comment: On my understanding of the docs you will need to create the chart and then rotate it by 90 deg.  The area will be between the `y0` and `y` values, so, in your example, that is the area under your line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was to rotate the chart itself as Cool Blue mentioned in the comment.

Answer (score 0):

It might not help you though,  what about using css like below

```
.area{
       fill:white;
      }

svg{
     background:#ccc;
    }
```